# What file is executed when pressing Win + Shift + S?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, filesystems, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-surface

From my understanding, shortcuts are convenient ways of executing files on a computer.

What file is executed when clicking **Win + Shift + S**, the shortcut that allows you to *take a snip of the screen and send it to onenote 2016*

BACKGROUND:

I have a surface book, and when double clicking the eraser I want it to take a snip and send it to onenote 2016 instead of onenote free edition. I figured I would find out the application activated from win shift S and then use the windows 10 surface customisation app to point the double click of the eraser to the win shift s application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 10 the process (what you referred to as a "file") that is executing when you hit <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> is OneNoteM.exe.  This process is by default configured to always run and it "listens" for the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> shortcut.  In other words, the process isn't launched when you hit the key combo, it has to be running for the key combo to do anything.  If you launch the process it just starts "listening" it doesn't invoke the screen snipping function.

Answer (score -2):

If you encounter windows' built-in screen capture crash (e.g. invisible topmost windows stealing focus from all other windows) then you can kill **ScreenClippingHost.exe** process.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).